# Text equality operator performance in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, data-structures, hash

How does this query work in terms of string comparison performance (assume there is a standard B-tree index on `last_name` ?

```
select * from employee where last_name = 'Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff';
```

So as it walks the B-Tree, I am assuming it it doesn't do a linear search on each character in the `last_name` field. EG, it doesn't start to check that the fist letter starts with a `W`... Assuming it doesn't do a linear comparison, what does it do?

I ask because I am considering to write my own duplicate prevention mechanism, but I want the performance to be sound. I was originally thinking of hashing each string (into some primitive datatype, probably a Long) that is coming in through an API, and storing the hash codes in a set/cache (each entry expires after 5 minutes). Any collisions would/could prompt a true duplicate check, where the already processed strings are stored in postgresql. But I'm thinking, would it be better to just simply query postgresql, in stead of maintaining my own memory based Set of Hashes that fluhses old entries after 5-10 minutes. I would probably use redis for scalability since multiple nodes will be reading different streams. Is my set of memory cached hash codes going to be faster than just querying indexed postgres String columns (full text matching not text searching) ?

Comment: 0) two people can have the same last_name, so you should not enfoce it to be unique 1) a btree index works excellent. 2) the compare function is basically strcmp(), but character encodeng could make it just a tiny bit more cosly 3) a database is for storing and retrieving things, not for implemnting your frontend-logic. 4) hashing only works for *exact* matching, in most cases you want to search for a *range* of values: `last_name ILIKE 'WOlf%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When strings are compared for equality, the function `texteq` is called.

If you look up the function in `src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c`, you will find that the comparison is made using the C library function `memcmp`. I doubt that you can get faster than that.

When you look up the value in a B-tree index, it will be compared to the values stored in each index page from the root page to the leaf page, that are at most 5 or 6 pages.

Frankly, I doubt that you can manage to be faster than that, but I wish you luck trying.

Comment: The B tree's will keep rebalancing though as new data comes in. I would be reading from the twitter streaming API at as about as fast as it can send me data without it being the firehouse access.

Comment: Sure, it may well be that you can code a faster solution for a specialized case. There will always be a trade-off between fast insert and fast search - if you beat an RDBMS in one, you may well be slower in the other.